# Illegal String Offset 'class' in PHP

Tags: php, joomla

I received this warning

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'class' in C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\libraries\cms\html\html.php on line 971

Warning: Illegal string offset 'class' in C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\libraries\cms\html\html.php on line 972

Warning: Illegal string offset 'class' in C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\libraries\cms\html\html.php on line 972
```

On joomla 3.3 (file path \libraries\cms\html\html.php) and the code is:

```
public static function calendar($value, $name, $id, $format = '%Y-%m-%d', $attribs = null)
{
    static $done;

    if ($done === null)
    {
        $done = array();
    }

    $attribs['class'] = isset($attribs['class']) ? $attribs['class'] : 'input-medium';//happen here 
    $attribs['class'] = trim($attribs['class'] . ' hasTooltip');//happen here 

    $readonly = isset($attribs['readonly']) && $attribs['readonly'] == 'readonly';
    $disabled = isset($attribs['disabled']) && $attribs['disabled'] == 'disabled';

   if (is_array($attribs))
    {
        $attribs = JArrayHelper::toString($attribs);
    }
.......
```

Shows that it had to do with $attribs['class']. And if I'm correct illegal string offset could mean that $attribs is not an array but a string. So is there any way to correct this?

I'm on PHP5.4

Comment: You have to check `$attribs` for `array` type before using `isset()`: `is_array($attribs) && isset($attribs['class']) ...`

Comment: Yes I know and that is why I'm asking since this is a problem came from joomla and I don't know how to 'convert' it to array

Comment: Another solution is that I need to downgrade my php version to 5.3 but I want it to remain UP to DATE

Comment: This is not an issue with the CMS, therefore anyone suggesting editing this code is wrong. The issue will be due to the extension that it trying to utilize this function.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
public static function calendar($value, $name, $id, $format = '%Y-%m-%d', $attribs = null)
{
}
```

Should be:

```
public static function calendar($value, $name, $id, $format = '%Y-%m-%d', $attribs = array())
{
}
```

Point is that by setting "null" to the variable by default, you actually say it's an empty string, or an empty variable. By setting "array()", you define the variable being an empty array.

Just by looking a little bit further, there is an array expected, since the code is looking for specific array_keys like: 'readonly' AND 'disabled'.

Comment: Then the problem is actually not starting in the code you show us: Can you tell how and where the function is called? (what's the code there?)
Seems like the function is called with "$attribs" given, but not as an array?

Comment: He's asking a question abnout an error generated by the use of the Joomla API. What he needs to do is find the place where the incorrect use is being passed in. Turn on error reporting to developer and look at the stack trace or grep for use of the calendar method.

Comment: I know, however, when there is usage and there is not any $format (and thus not any $attribs) given (those are not required to use by that code), there's no problem in the call of the calendar method. That's why I'm pointing in the direction I did.